# Drupal 7, trying to "theme" the node links i.e. "Add new Comment" "Read More" etc

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-comments

I'm spending more and more time here, and constantly wishing Drupal was easier to understand then I'm finding it, oh well :)

so todays question is, I'm trying to remove the "2 comment" and "1 new comment" links from a node in Teaser view. I do however want to keep the "Read More" and "Add new Comment" links.

So I've found all this is stored in "print render($content['links']);"

I have also discovered that **"Read More"** can be requested using **"print render($content['links']['node']);"** and all **3 comment links** can be pulled out using **"print render($content['links']['comment']);"**

What I cannot work out is how to break down the Comment part so I can strip out the 2 I dont need.

anyone know?

thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, I believe I have found the function I want to override "function comment_node_view($node, $view_mode) " its in the comment.module file in the comment modules folder. I can't seem to effect it though when I try to override it by putting it in my Template.php file and add my theme_ to the function name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions that you are looking for are probably [hook_node_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) and [hook_comment_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view_alter/7).

FYI, a quick fix is also possible via CSS where you can simply hide the offending DIV.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I will give it ago as soon as I can. I try to aviod the CSS hide solution as I want less server overheads. I find Drupal quite heavy weight at best.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what @coleopterist said, the following worked well for me:

```
mytheme_node_view_alter(&$build) {
    if ($build['#view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
        $build['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['title'] = t('Read More &raquo;');
    }
}
```